# How to delay expensive calculation in postgres until final steps

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, aggregate-functions, postgresql-9.1

I have a simple postgres 9.1 query that contains a very expensive calculation:

```
SELECT a, b, sum(c), very_expensive_calculation(f)
FROM my_table
GROUP BY a, b, f
```

The function very_expensive_calculation() is a custom function of mine (non-aggregate) that runs a recursive summation of values behind the scenes, and because of this it takes a while. The problem occurs because there are many duplicates in my_table because it's very de-normalized so it runs once for each row when it should only run on distinct values. I tried the following to run the function on the pre-grouped values:

```
SELECT a, b, c_sum, very_expensive_calculation(f)
FROM (
  SELECT a, b, sum(c) c_sum, f
  FROM my_table
  GROUP BY a, b, f
) pre_group
```

This cuts down on the number of runs for very_expensive_calculations() because if the original query contained 100 rows but the grouped contained only 10, then I have a 90% reduction in executions. However, this is hacky and is coming with other problems (there's a lot more criteria and columns w/ custom logic that I'm not showing, and they're suffering from this hack).

Can I run the first query but delay very_expensive_calculation() to run on the already grouped values for *f*, possibly by declaring very_expensive_function() as an aggregate?

EDIT (@gordon linoff): Would the following behave the same as the answer mentioned below?

```
WITH fvec AS (
 select f, very_expensive_calculation(f) as vec
 from (select distinct f from my_table) mt
)
Select a, b, sum(c), fvec.vec
from my_table agg inner join fvec on agg.f = fvec.f
group by a, b, fvec.vec
```

Our auto-generated code can do WITH clauses easily but I'm not sure if this behaves the same as the join solution below.

Comment: And what's the function definition? If the function is marked as `STABLE`/`IMMUTABLE` pg should optimize on it's own.

Comment: It's marked as STABLE, but it's inherently expensive (has to recurse a tree structure). But even if I were to optimize the function more so, it is still being executed too often because of the denormalized data.

Comment: If function is `STABLE` and `COST` is set high enough the function shouldn't be called more than once with the same input.

Comment: Very high level input to your question, but consider writing expensive function in C if you need to squeeze every ounce of performance out of it.

Comment: I had no idea about the COST and input issue. Fantastic. I will do some research about that because I was about to implement a cache for repeated values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your original query, I think this might be the cheapest way would be to do the calculation only one time for each `f` and `join` the results back in:

```
select agg.*, fvec.fec
from (SELECT a, b, sum(c) as sumc
      FROM my_table
      GROUP BY a, b, f
     ) agg join
     (select f, very_expensive_calculation(f) as vec
      from (select distinct f from my_table) mt
     ) fvec
     on agg.f = fvec.f;
```

I don't see how writing a custom-aggregation function would help *unless* the aggregation function stashed already computed values.  The aggregation function is going to be called for each row in the original table, not each row in the post-aggregated results.

Comment: Unfortunately we use code generation which is what makes purely custom SQL difficult. Would the following work the same with the query parsing and optimizer? (Put above in my main post EDIT)

Comment: @user1661467 . . . That should work well.  I believe that Postgres materializes CTEs, so there is a slight overhead for that, but nothing significant.